# Nested ListView, StreamBuilder and Subcollection

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a nested ListView, but don't know, if I can combine 2 streambuilders in a nested view, as it doesn't work. In the second StreamBuilder with the subcollection query, no data seems to be returned and I can't figure out why.

When I hardcode the document id I don't get any error, but still the query doesn't seem to return any data.

Does anybody know, how to construct a nested listview with streambuilders and Firestore?

```
  List<Widget> buildStreamedListView() {
return [ StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('course')
              .document(widget.data.documentID)
              .collection('section')
              .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
      return Expanded(child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          //return buildListItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]);

          return Card(
            child: ExpansionTile(
              title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['name']),
              children: <Widget>[
                StreamBuilder(
                  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('course')
                    .document(widget.data.documentID)
                    .collection('section')
                    .document('4CjAZEQ416NYpu3ra3OE')
                    .collection('page')
                    .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snap) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snap.data.documents.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Text('Hello you');
                      }
                    );
                  }
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      ));
    },
  )];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The reason that I had strange errors was, that in the second builder function I didn't add the following code:

```
if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
```

Once I added it, it worked. Seems the data was just not ready yet, hence it couldn't be read and hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to also test for `snap.hasData()` in your nested `StreamBuilder`.